# Identify element is not present selenium webdriver javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, assert

I have tried various techniques to assert that an element is not present in Selenium javascript But to no avail, I cant assert of the findElements.length function is the closest I have gotten.

```
   const noofElements = driver.findElements(By.css("#foo")).then(elements => console.log(elements.length));

   assert.strictEqual(noofElements, 0);
```

I can spit out the result of the findelements.length but cant assert against it. I have also tried with .size but that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
   const noofElements = driver.findElements(By.css("#foo")).then(elements => assert.strictEqual(elements.length, 0));
  

Or

 const noofElements = await driver.findElements(By.css("#foo")).length
  assert.strictEqual(elements.length, 0));
```

You should assert it inside the then or use await ,

Comment: The const isnt being called. there. Just declared.???

Comment: You can remove the constant for first approach you don't need it